# Admob on android - UUIDs, cookies etc

Tags: android, admob

Ok, so I am very new to the world of Android apps (in fact, I've just about got past the hello worlds and understanding the sdk). I was looking into how free apps make money and Admob seems to be one of the most popular ways to put ads on your app - I should state that my study is academic rather than inclined toward how-can-I-make-money-from-this (at least right now :))

Now, I've been toying with the emulator and some apps which use admob and find they send this isu="xxxxx...xxx" (some 32 character hex I believe) to get ads, which from wikis I gather is a unique ID for a device. I'm curious as to how this is a) calculated and b) stored on my device (a cookie perhaps?). I'm pretty sure it won't be easy to answer a) but I would really like to know about b) - after all if there is a cookie on my device, I have every right to know where the little file is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 32 character hex value is just an MD5 Hash of your Android device ID.  The SDK does not record the real device ID of the phone that is requesting ads.  You also do not need to specify this in your app to get ads though.  All you need is an AdMob Publisher ID to start getting ads, and you can get one for free by registering your app at [admob.com](http://admob.com/).

Check out the [AdMob docs](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/) for more information on getting started with AdMob.

Comment: Interesting, thats exactly what I suspected, but I tried doing an md5 on my device ID. Didn't quite match the ISU. Is it converted to a hex string before conversion? Not that its hugely important. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it does before doing the MD5.  I just know that the isu that is passed in the request is the same value as the string you would want to give to addTestDevice if you wanted to whitelist your device for test ads during testing.